# Swift Programmatically Change X,Y of UIButton

Tags: xcode, swift, coordinates

I've been working at this and searching the web but I can seem to find the solution. I have a button that I'm wanting to place based on the size of the device. This is not a problem I created little switch statement that handles the "based on device" part.

I have a UITextField that I've programmatically created and placed in the view and I use this code to do so:

```
locationField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 90, y: 250, width: 150, height: 40))
```

The problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to get the button to place. I have created the button on the storyboard and thought that something like this would work:

```
goArrow.frame = CGRect(x: 240, y: 250, width: goArrow.frame.size.width, height: goArrow.frame.size.height)
```

But that isn't getting me any where. I'm pretty new to Swift and just trying to find my way around in the dark.

Comment: "that isn't getting me any where" Meaningless. What happens? What is `goArrow` - can you prove that it is even something in the interface?

Comment: If you created the button in the storyboard, why don't you use autolayout constraints to position the button based on the screen size? That is what constraints are for, after all.

Comment: One possibility is that you're fighting auto-layout. If you have auto-layout enabled, then changing the frame of the button is futile, since auto-layout will simply put the button back where it was based on the auto-layout constraints. You have three choices 1) disable auto-layout 2) modify the constraints programmatically to move the button 3) set up the constraints in storyboard so that the button positions itself auto-magically for each device.

Comment: I suggest watching the CS193P video (free from iTunes) that introduces auto-layout, so that you have an overview of the capabilities of auto-layout.

Comment: Thank you, @user3386109 for being constructive rather than critical. I will attempt making changes that you have suggested.

Comment: Have you even linked it between code and storyboard? And like @user3386109 said, if you have a constraint added to it and you move it by changing the frame it will pop back after viewWillLayoutSubviews() gets called

Comment: @Arbitur, I did have it linked. I did not have any constraints to it but changing it as I stated in my post had no affect and the button just hung out in the top left corner. There are constraints on other elements in the view but not on the button.

Comment: @bnjmn.myers I also had a lot issues like that when I started. It helped me a lot to learn how to set things programatically. Storyboard is a great tool, but it has a lot of quirks. It is a bit more work, but more predictable when this is al new.

Comment: If you add it in storyboard but without the constraint while the other views have, it will pop to origin {0, 0}. Either add a constraint and then change the constraints or add it programmally then you can change its frame all you want.